# ANT Build error

Tags: android, linux

This might be a long shot but I hope someone can help me as I have spent all day to get to this point and I desperately just want to get the code working now!

The guide I am using is from here http://rmtheis.wordpress.com/2011/08/06/using-tesseract-tools-for-android-to-create-a-basic-ocr-app/ and I am following the instructions word for word.

It tells me to ensure that you get `“BUILD SUCCESSFUL” when ant finishes`

I however do not! Instead i get an error message saying

> ricki@ubuntu:~/tesseract-android-tools/tesseract-android-tools$ ant
>   release Buildfile: build.xml
>
> BUILD FAILED
>   /home/ricki/tesseract-android-tools/tesseract-android-tools/build.xml:46:
>   sdk.dir is missing. Make sure to generate local.properties using
>   'android update project'

Its quite likely this is too specific for anyone to help, in which case feel free to delete. However if anyone has an idea on what I need to do to fix this please please help me!

KInd regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message states you have to set your sdk dir in the local.properties file. Alternatively you can set your sdk directory in the ANDROID_HOME env variable.

Comment: sorry for such a silly question - does this mean i can do it inside the project in eclipse?

Comment: Sure. Create the file and put sdk.dir=part/to/android/sdk/home

Comment: Setting the environment variable 'ANDROID_HOME' does not help. It's probably a different variable that needs to be set.

Comment: Locally for me the sdk.dir is already set in local.properties, and yet I have this issue. Any ideas?